# Change table depending on radiobutton selection

Tags: javascript, html-table, radio-button

I have two different datasets of worldcupresults from 2006 and 2010. I want to be able to select the 2006 radiobutton and display the results for that year in 
 a table, i also want to select 2010 and show those results for that year in a table.
The 2006 table displays correctly but when the 2010 radiobutton is selected, nothing happens. Any help is appreciated.

This is the code that I have tried but it is not working successfully.

```
if(document.getElementById("radiobutton2006").checked = true)
{
     $ ('#table2006').append(`<tr><td>${value.team}</td <td>${value.result}</td></tr>`);
}
else if(document.getElementById("radiobutton2010").checked = true)
{
     $ ('#table2010').append(`<tr><td>${value.team}</td> <td>${value.result}</td></tr>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **if statement** requires the specified condition to be either **truthy** or **falsy**. You are using assignment operator `=` in your **if-else** condition. The `=` sign isn't really necessary as `checked` is a `boolean` property.

```
if(document.getElementById("radiobutton2006").checked)
{
     $ ('#table2006').append(`<tr><td>${value.team}</td <td>${value.result}</td></tr>`);
}
else if(document.getElementById("radiobutton2010").checked)
{
     $ ('#table2010').append(`<tr><td>${value.team}</td> <td>${value.result}</td></tr>`);
}
```

But if you want to continue with equality operator, you should replace `=` with `==` or `===`. Note that `==` and `===` are not same. `===` also checks for the type.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to build on Elishs' answer a bit. You appear to be using jQuery, so I updated the document.getElementById appropriately.
Also, as mentioned by Elish, there are two forms of equality in JavaScript. == is weak equality, and === is strict. You should generally use strict, because there are situations where == can cause unexpected behavior.

```
if ($("#radiobutton2006").prop('checked') === true)
```

See:

- [JavaScript - The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)
- [JQuery - Prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)